# Pandas library `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__builtin__'`

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have been using the pandas library successfully for a while but recently I have begun to receive the following error message when attempting to import in scripts. I have no idea what I have done to cause this or how it can be solved. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    import __builtin__ as builtins
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__builtin__'`

Comment: This sounds like a python2 vs python3 installation problem. Can you give some info on your system and how you installed pandas?

Comment: This was my initial thought as well. Pandas was installed with pip3 as follows
`pip3 install pandas`
Running the command again gives a response saying that the requirement is already satisfied. 
Running `pip3 show pandas` returns the following:
```Name: pandas
Version: 0.23.4
Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics
Home-page: http://pandas.pydata.org
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: pytz, python-dateutil, numpy
Required-by: activityio```

Comment: It's weird.. Looking at the try/except block in `compat/_init__.py` (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/compat/__init__.py) this catches an ImportError, of which ModuleNotFoundError is a subclass, so this should be handled in the code.

Comment: Why should that ImportError occur in the first place?

Comment: If you are running python3, the `__builtins__` module is now called `builtins`, so this should give an exception and be handled in the except block. For some reason this goes wrong for you.

Comment: So that's an issue with the pandas installation. Perhaps if I uninstall pandas and attempt to install again it might have a more up to date version of this module.