# FastAI load_learner() | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__builtin__'

Tags: python-3.x, torch, built-in, fast-ai, dill

To minimise code, I want to use [load_learner()](https://docs.fast.ai/learner.html#load_model), instead of creating a new `learner` every time.

`with open()` works, but leaves me with setting up the large amount of learner code.

**Update**: I've been using [dill](https://pypi.org/project/dill/) instead of `pickle`. Which I believe doesn't work well with FastAI.

---

I get thrown this error on `load_learner()`

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__builtin__'
```

Supposedly, `__builtins__` was renamed to `builtins` in Python 3.
[Source 1](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/953#issuecomment-521557773)
[Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52935624/pandas-library-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-builtin)

##### Versions

```
torch==1.7.1
fastai==2.7.7
fastcore==1.5.6
torch==1.7.1
torchvision==0.8.2
```

---

`predict.py`

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_path = project_params.file_path
    learner = project_params.learner
    model = load_learner(file_path.model, cpu=learner.cpu)  # !
```

```
(venv) me@ubuntu-pcs:~/PycharmProjects/project$ python project_model/predict.py
'foo/data/bar.dvc' didn't change, skipping    
Running stage 'predict':
> python foo/predict.py
/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py:52: UserWarning: CUDA initialization: Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx (Triggered internally at  /pytorch/c10/cuda/CUDAFunctions.cpp:100.)
  return torch._C._cuda_getDeviceCount() > 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/PycharmProjects/project/foo/predict.py", line 35, in <module>
    model = load_learner(file_path.model, cpu=learner.cpu)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastai/learner.py", line 414, in load_learner
    try: res = torch.load(fname, map_location=map_loc, pickle_module=pickle_module)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 595, in load
    return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 764, in _legacy_load
    magic_number = pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__builtin__'
ERROR: failed to reproduce 'predict': failed to run: python foo/predict.py, exited with 1
```

---

`params.yaml`

```
learner:
  cpu: False
# ...
file_path:
  model: ./project_model/data/learner.pkl
```

Comment: have you tried installing `future` package?:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63306626/how-to-fix-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-builtin-in-pycharm

Comment: I get the same error with `import builtin`

Comment: Do you get the same error if you manually run `python project_model/predict.py`? If so this may not be related to DVC.

Comment: I get the same error when running `python project_model/predict.py `

Comment: It seems like an issue with the code/libraries. Have you tried creating new environment?